# Nginx equivalent of Apache query string rule

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, woocommerce

we recently moved to a nginx server for one of our WordPress site. We've had an issue with Cloudflare where the content-type of a ajax request was modified which was causing issue with Stripe integration and it didn't render.

We fixed it with the below code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \?wc-ajax=update_order_review$
Header set Content-Type text/html
```

Tried the below code in Nginx

```
location ~ /?wc-ajax=update_order_review$ {
  add_header Content-Type text/html;
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't work and didn't find any solution to rewrite the same in Nginx.
Can you please help sort this out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$args` to access query string (without `?`) and `$arg_name` to access a query parameter `name`.

[Here is official Nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables)

So for you you may try:

```
location / {
   if ($arg_wc-ajax ~ "^update_order_review$") {
      add_header Content-Type text/html;
   }
}
```